# How to clear all sticky manipulators on (string)stream?

Tags: c++, iostream, iomanip

I am clearing a `std::stringstream` the usual way:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
for(...; ...; ...) {
    ... // Use ss.
    if(some_condition_to_reset_stringstream) {
        ss.str(std::string());
        ss.clear();
    }
    ... // Use ss some more.
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not clear any sticky manipulators (`std::hex`, `std::setfill`, etc.).

Is there some way to reset the entire `std::stringstream`, including any IO manipulators? Or do I have to manually reset each manipulator individually (hopefully not forgetting any in the process)?

Comment: Just throw away the string stream and construct a new one.

Comment: @MatteoItalia The stringstream is used within a parsing loop, and must be reset on certain iterations, but not all. So unfortunately I cannot construct a new one every time.

Comment: @zennehoy: You could save the initial flags and simply reset them via `std::ostringstream::flags`. Note that you also have to save `::fill`, `::width` and `::precision` if you want to revert all changes.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently in C++11 it should be possible to swap stringstreams:

```
if(some_condition_to_reset_stringstream) {
    std::ostringstream().swap(ss);
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have a compiler that supports this (g++ 4.8.2), so I can't test whether this clears sticky manipulators (I don't see why it should not though, once implemented).

Still looking for an alternative, since my compiler doesn't support it :)